# Protrusion \lpcode and \rpcode for otf font feature characters?

Tags: luatex, protrusion

Using lualatex, Linux, TeXlive 2023.

Without using `microtype` I can directly set character protrusions using `\lpcode` and `\rpcode.` This works for me, since I use a custom OpenType font with known properties,
and only use utf-8.

But what about characters that are in the OpenType features? For example, I have character `A.alt` (alternative glyph for A) that is accessed via an OpenType feature. I would like to set its protrusions different than the values for ordinary A.

Can this be directly done, using `\lpcode` and `\rpcode`? If it can, the syntax is not obvious. I suppose I could define macros that change the protrusion settings when I invoke the features, but that seems too brute-force even for me!

I notice that `microtype` has a nearly-undocumented method for doing this. It is barely mentioned in the doc PDF. I discovered it by inspecting some of the built-in protrusion files that come with the package. In `microtype` notation I would so something such as `/A.alt = {30,40}` for the protrusion.

Comment: `luaotfload` provides the auxiliary function `name_of_slot` (which is also what microtype uses) --: `\lpcode<font>= \directlua{tex.print(luaotfload.aux.slot_of_name(font.current(),"A.alt"))}=100`

Comment: @Robert Can you clarify that? Is `<font>` one of the fontnumber codes, or something else? Each time I try your code, also with variations, it seems that the slot number is not defined. But the font was already set, and the requested character is certainly in the font.

Comment: `\lpcode` expects a command that has been defined via `\font`, so for example: `\input luaotfload.sty
\font\x="EB Garamond-Regular" \x
\lpcode\x \directlua{tex.print(luaotfload.aux.slot_of_name(font.current(),"a.sc"))}=100`

Comment: (I had a stray `=` in my first reply.)

Comment: I got the revised code to work, after further revision: First I used `\edef` to get the number from `\dirctlua{...}` and assigned it to \temp@n`. Then (using your definition of `\x` I wrote `\lpcode\x\temp@n=10` and it worked. Fo a reason I canot explain, it did not work using `\lpcode\x\directlua...`. Perhaps you can post code as the answer.